# When in KDE under Konsole its windows a terminal shell bash is running, how to ask in a shell script for the Konsole_nn number?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, kde

In KDE there is one superordinate Konsole.

Under this superordinate Konsole I have many Windows open. In each window the title line has the inscription "Konsole nn". Where nn is the konsole number, with different number in different window.

In each window as shell bash is running.

Each shell is attached to a pseudoterminal "/dev/pts/mm" with numbers mm.

In the bash I am running scripts.

I would like out of a script to ask for the corresponding Konsole_nn number for a specified pts/mm pseudoterminal-number.

Is there a way?

Or, at least, if that is not possible, to ask in which Konsole_nn number the current bash is running.

How to do?

Regards == 31.01.2023 14:16

Comment: Does [terminal emulator - Linux how to get window title with just shell script? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/481285/linux-how-to-get-window-title-with-just-shell-script) answer your question?

Comment: == 20.03.2023 18:14 to answer of DavidPostill, 31.01.2023 13:24 :: Thank you. Using verbatime that link and others brought no succsess. But based upon your answer I have found  the utiliy "wmctrl". This "wmctrl" is just that tool all the years I thought it should exist. This will bring me   foreward. Yet in the moment it is not a solution to my needs. "wmctrl" lists all the windows line by line with the title at end of line. And the title in each line is "Konsole". In my windows in their title bar are the names "Konsole 2", Konsole 3", etc. I need the complete name with number. Regards.

Comment: == 20.03.2023 19:50 :: addendum :: achieved a progress. As I wrote, "wmctrl" reports for all windows with the shells bash in it, which I have created under one Konsole, the same title name "Konsole",  despite in their title bars the windows write "Konsole 1", "Konsole 2", etc. This is due to the fact that I have created them by the GUI utility "Konsole", which automatically named them "1", "2",.. When  use "wmctrl" to set the "long name" to "WE_Konsole_13", this new name is correctly listed by "wmctrl". And this new name is in the window correctly written in the title bar. --hurra--. Regards.

Comment: == 21.03.2023 09:23 addemdum:: I have discovered  "xwininfo" etc. I am stupid, have neglected until now all regarding windows. Thanks, Regards

Comment: == 21.03.2023 10:50 addendum :: now I have reviewed all relevant utilities that are installed on my current system. My result is: Correlation beween (a) window ID, (b)  PID, and (c) window title name is only  yielded by utility "wmctrl". This correlation  as basics allows me to develop scripts to overcome missings in Linux systems. But I have  read that "wmctrl" is dependent on the "EWMH" specification. Thus I have the question: is that portable, is that reliable for now and for the future. Please does someone know about this. Regards